# missing app-level build.gradle file. Command line gradle

Tags: android, gradle, command-line, build.gradle

I am trying to create the android project from command line using gradle.

Used the below command :

`android create project --activity [activityname] --package [packagename] --target [androidtarget] --path [projectpath] --gradle --gradle-version [gradleversion]`

But this doesn't create the project with new project structure. It creates the files and folders according to **old project structure**. 
The project directory should have 1 top-level build.gradle file and another module-level build.gradle file right ?

Using the above command, there is **no module level build.gradle** file found. Hence I am not able to add my dependencies.

I cannot use android studio, how can I do achieve this with command line ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why can't you use android studio?@Sunshine

Comment: I am not supposed to use.